# Почему функция SymEnumerateSymbols некорректно работает в Windows Vista?

Tags: winapi, interop, vista, c#

Код, импортирующий функцию:

```
    [DllImport("Imagehlp.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    private static extern bool SymEnumerateSymbols(IntPtr process, IntPtr baseDll, IntPtr callback, object context);
```

Код, формирующий указатель на функцию, который передаётся в параметр callback:

```
private delegate bool LoadSymbolDelegate(string name, IntPtr symbolAddress, uint size, IntPtr context);
...
IntPtr collector = Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(new LoadSymbolDelegate(loader.LoadSymbol));
```

В Windows XP функция даёт вполне правдоподобный список экспортированных функций указанной DLL-ки. В Windows Vista функция выдаёт только первые буквы названий функций.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если и Vista, и XP - 32 бита, возможно, дело в ANSI/Unicode строках. Для проверки можно попробовать другой Charset (Charset.Unicode, Charset.Ansi) и другие прототипы (SymEnumerateSymbols, SymEnumerateSymbolsW).

Comment: Отправил патч, буду ждать результатов...

Comment: Получил отзыв.

Работает тот вариант, у которого вызывается SymEnumerateSymbols с CharSet = CharSet.Ansi. Спасибо.